# Conditional array as a parameter inside array

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
const obj = new plugin.process({
  extensions: [...bindings, a, b]
});
```

Is there anyway to make the bindings optional based on another parm?

Say I have a boolean flag

```
 const obj = new plugin.process({
      extensions: [...bindings && myFlag, a, b]
    });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just construct the array before the `.process()` call and don't squeeze everything in one fanzy line of code

Answer (score 1):

You could simply construct the array before passing it into `process`.

First create your default array, this could be:

```js
const extensions = [a, b]
```

Then add an extra condition in case your boolean is true:

```js
if(myFlag) {
  extensions.push(...bindings)
}
```

Combining this together:

```js
const extensions = [a, b]

if(myFlag) {
  extensions.push(...bindings)
}

const obj = new plugin.process({
  extensions
});
```

If `bindings` need to be added before `a` and `b`, we can write logic like this:

```js
const extensions = []

if(myFlag) {
  extensions.push(...bindings)
}

extensions.push(a, b)

const obj = new plugin.process({
  extensions
});
```

Comment: The content of `bindings` has to be placed _before_ `a` and `b`

Comment: @Andreas Added some more information

Comment: @Andreas bindings will be added before `a` and `b` since you first push bindings, then `a` and `b`

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```js
const obj = new plugin.process({
  extensions: [
    ...bindings,
    ...(myFlag ? [a, b] : [])
  ]
});
```

Comment: This will work, but it's bad practice in general. It's not because it's compact that it's good. It's harder to read and understand what is going on.